# mongoDb Atlas - In general, What affects my writing rate here?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, bigdata, mongodb-atlas

I am using an Atlas cluster with M60 tier configured with IOPS of 3099.
I am trying to write 116,550,000 documents, waging at around 12 KB on average per doc, as fast as possible.(optimally in less then 6 hours)
I have 6 compound indexes made of multiple fields.

My question is: I would like to know what, in principle, affects my writing speed and essentially holds my speed from getting any faster.
Is it the IOPS? If I increase the IOPS say to 9000 will I see a drastic change in writing speed?
Is sharding the answer here? And if so, can I use multiple shards in the, lets say M30 tier, but with more IOPS and achieve my goal?

Thank to all the responders :)

The best writing speed I managed to achieve was 1200 docs per sec, using node. optional: I have a spark cluster with mongodb-spark-connector as a sending option. But I think the problem is in the mongo server and not the client.

Answer (score 0):

before applying sharding I recommend you to try to create a new instance writing in parallel to check if the issue is in node. I'm saying that because we had the same issue.. and the problem it was node, we ran 2 apps in parallel to increase the number of writes and we solved the issue doing this. If after this test do not increase the number of docs per second you can try to configure the sarding!

Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).